# CSS parent div 5px more than the child div

Tags: html, css

Two divs are there one containing the other. I want the parent to have an height more than 5px of the containing child. The contents in the child is dynamic. Can i achieve this using css?

Edit : Without adding padding/margin to the parent div, can i achieve this?

```css
.parent {
  background: red
}

.child {
  background: green
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"> some dynamic textsss </div>
</div>
```

Comment: read about `position` css property

Comment: Using `padding` you can achieve this

Comment: Thank you for the answers. Can i achieve this using the height of the parent div?

Comment: question is not clear at all... :(

Comment: Can you please take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add a padding-bottom to the parent div.

```
.parent{background: red; padding-bottom: 5px;} .child{background: green}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `calc()` *function* for the `.child`'s `height`:

```css
.parent {
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}

.child {
  height: calc(100% - 5px); /* takes 100% of the parent's height - 5px */
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"> some dynamic textsss </div>
</div>
```

Or just add the `box-sizing: border-box` and `padding-bottom: 5px` to the `.parent` *div* and set `height: 100%` for the `.child` *div*:

```css
.parent {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 200px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  background: red;
}

.child {
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"> some dynamic textsss </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript. Here is your code.

```js
var parent = document.getElementById("parent");
var child = document.getElementById("child");
var height = child.offsetHeight  + 5 + "px";
parent.style.height = height;
```

```css
.parent {
  background-color: red;
}

.child {
  background-color: green
}
```

```html
<div class="parent" id="parent">
<div class="child" id="child"> some dynamic textsss </div>
</div>
```